# Collapse all div knowing the function

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function like below (i'm igniting js using chrome extension). My objective is to collapse all 50 groups using a pre-made function without changing every parameter number.

I'm looking for

```
myapp.divs.CollapseGroup(1);
myapp.divs.CollapseGroup(2);
myapp.divs.CollapseGroup(3);
myapp.divs.CollapseGroup(4);
```

so i tiried this:

```
window.onload = function () { 
for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
myapp.divs.CollapseGroup(i);
}
}
```

the CollapseGroup parameter doesn't change.

Comment: impossible to help you debug this with the information provided.

Comment: Sorry, i'm looking for
myapp.divs.CollapseGroup(1);
myapp.divs.CollapseGroup(2);
myapp.divs.CollapseGroup(3);
myapp.divs.CollapseGroup(4);

Comment: Which is what that code should be doing

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I've just updated the question for better understanding.

Comment: what is the error / bug you are experiencing?

Comment: it gives me nothing
    myapp.divs.CollapseGroup();